# How to say the term "招" and "式" in English?

Tags: meaning, word

It's used as a classifier, like this:

> "亢龙有悔"是"降龙十八掌"中的**一招**.

and

> **一招一式**他都记得清清楚楚.

So how to say it in English?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/faq#can-i-request-a-translation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally it's called 'move'.

To be precise, 招 is 'move' and 式 is 'stance' or 'form'.

When it comes to a specific move, you can use words like catch (手 as in 擒拿手), hit (打), reach (长拳), kick (踢) etc.

> 一招一式他都记得清清楚楚。
>
> Every move is imprinted on his mind.

Comment: I will vote you up when I get 15 reps. :)